# Advantages of forwarding references as functor arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

There are so many talk about the new C++ forwarding references.
However sometimes in a particular situation it's still not clear to me whether they provide any advantage or not.

It's clear that passing heavy state functors (just like random number generators) by value is not a good idea. So let's use references. Okay, but...

...is there any advantage of using **forwarding references** like

```
template <class T, class Functor>
T func(T x, Functor &&f)
{
    T y;
    // do some computations involving f(x) and store it in y
    return y;
}
```

instead of **const references**

```
template <class T, class Functor>
T func(T x, const Functor &f)
{
    T y;
    // do some computations involving f(x) and store it in y
    return y;
}
```

in functions that take functor objects without forwarding them?

The main aspect of the question is the performance consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The choice depends on what `f` does, whether it makes sense to accept an rvalue, whether the function object is expected to be small, and whether reference semantics makes sense. Most standard library algorithms take function objects by value, because they are expected to have little to no state, and taking by value can be more efficient.

A good example for taking forwarding references is `std::shuffle`:

```
template< class RandomIt, class URNG >
void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URNG&& g );
```

The URNG has to be taken by reference, as 1) it's not required to be copyable and 2) you really don't want to copy it (both because RNGs can be pretty expensive to copy and because users usually want `shuffle` to change the RNG's state; they would be pretty surprised if two calls to `shuffle` with the same RNG object resulted in the same "random" order). You also can't take it by const reference, because then you can't call `operator()` on it - generating a random number changes the RNG's state.

The choice is then between a non-const lvalue reference, `URNG&` and a forwarding reference, `URNG&&`. Since sometimes you do want to accept an rvalue URNG - for instance when you want to shuffle to the same reproducible order, so you create a generator with a fixed seed at the call point - [the latter was chosen](http://wg21.link/lwg1432).

Comment: The only frustrating thing with forwarding references is if you want to access member types, you need to remove the reference from them by using typename std::remove_reference<T>::type which messes up readability.

Comment: @plasmacel write an alias, remove it once, and never worry about it again :)

Answer (score 3):

The *forwarding reference* version is able to bind either to `Functor`s with `operator()` declared **const** or **non const**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that compiles on forward reference but not const reference:

```
template <class T, class Functor>
T func(T x, Functor &&f)
{
    T y;
    y = f(x);
    return y;
}

template <class T, class Functor>
T func2(T x, const Functor &f)
{
    T y;
    y = f(x);
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    auto add_a = [=](int x) mutable { return ++a; };
    func(0, add_a); // compile
    func2(0, add_a); // does not compile
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eeb21a57d66452b

Because you `mutable` lambda does not have `operator const (int)`

In other words, invoke a mutable lambda will mutate it, however you cannot mutate const reference. So you need to use forward reference.